# Is there any difference in meaning between "work out a problem" and "work through a problem"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Can you please tell if there is any difference in meaning between *work out a problem* and *work through a problem*? For example:

> I can't tell why the laptop is going haywire not, but I'll **work out** that problem.
>
> I can't tell why the laptop is going haywire not, but I'll **work through** that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In American English, “work something out” and “work through something” have overlapping fields of meaning.

“Work something out” frequently means to resolve something.

> I am serious about working this dispute out without lawyers and without jeopardizing our relationship

indicates a desire to end a dispute amicably.

“Work through something” frequently means to analyze something carefully with a view to understanding.

> I am trying to work through Ricardo’s theory of value, but am finding it quite obscure

indicates a desire to fully understand that theory.

However, we frequently want to understand something in order to resolve it. In such situations, either locution may spring to mind.

> I am trying to work through this notice of a tax deficiency

with the unstated purpose of resolving it

> Yes, I am studying the notice of tax deficiency. I want to work this out promptly

Either phrase may be appropriate in such a situation. They have different primary meanings, but those meanings are often closely related.

Answer (score 1):

*work out* a problem  means to figure out how to do something.

The Brits use work out often where a AmE speaker would use figure out. However, work out is not only British.

"I can't seem to *work out* those parking tickets." [Why I got them]

Work through a problem means to go step by step when faced with a problem in order to resolve it using a process, even if that process is informal.

"We have to *work through* the structural load issues before starting to build."

Comment: Maybe I'm old, but I first used 'work out' to mean 'carry out one or a series of arithmetic operations', e.g. work out the cost of 12.85 tonnes of ready-mix concrete if one tonne costs £95.00 including delivery.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I agree but didn't put in every single thing. I actually had that and then took it out. Bad choice on my part.